# Specify the sort order with LC_COLLATE so lowercase is before uppercase

Tags: linux, sort

Given the file:

```
$ cat file
1
a
C
B
2
c
3
A
b
```

By default `sort` will:

```
$ sort file
1
2
3
a
A
b
B
c
C
```

With `LC_COLLATE=C` so will sort in uppercase letter before lowercase:

```
$ LC_COLLATE=C sort file
1
2
3
A
B
C
a
b
c
```

Is it possible to get sort to reverse the case ordering, that is digits, lowercase then uppercase?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't know of any locales that, by default, sort in that order.  The solution is to create a custom locale with a customized sort order.  If anyone, four years later, wants to sort in a custom fashion, here's the trick.

The vast majority of locales don't specify their own sort order, but rather copy the sort order defined in `/usr/share/i18n/locales/iso14651_t1_common` so that is what you will want to edit.  Rather than change the sort order for nearly every locale by modifying the original `iso14651_t1_common`, I suggest you make a copy.  Details about how the sort order works and how to create a custom locale in your `$HOME` directory without root access are found [in this answer to a similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/288333/how-can-i-make-ls-show-dotfiles-first-while-staying-case-insensitive/361006#361006).

Take a look at how `a` and `A` are ordered based on their entries in `iso14651_t1_common`:

```
<U0061> <a>;<BAS>;<MIN>;IGNORE # 198 a
<U0041> <a>;<BAS>;<CAP>;IGNORE # 517 A
```

`b` and `B` are similar:

```
<U0062> <b>;<BAS>;<MIN>;IGNORE # 233 b
<U0042> <b>;<BAS>;<CAP>;IGNORE # 550 B
```

We see that on the first pass, both `a` and `A` have the collating symbol `<a>`, while both `b` and `B` have the collating symbol `<b>`.  Since `<a>` appears before `<b>` in `iso14651_t1_common`, `a` and `A` are tied before `b` and `B`.  The second pass doesn't break the ties because all four characters have the collating symbol `<BAS>`, but during the third pass the ties are resolved because the collating symbol for lowercase letters `<MIN>` appears on line 3467, before the collating symbol for uppercase letters `<CAP>` (line 3488).  So the sort order ends up as `a`, `A`, `b`, `B`.

Swapping the first and third collating symbols would sort letters first by case (lower then upper), then by accent (`<BAS>` means non-accented), then by alphabetical order.  **However**, both `<MIN>` and `<CAP>` come before the numeric digits, so this would have the unwanted effect of putting digits after letters.

The easiest way to keep digits first while making *all* lowercase letters come before *all* uppercase letters is to force all letters to tie during the first comparison by setting them all equal to `<a>`.  To make sure that they sort alphabetically within case, change the last collating symbol from `IGNORE` to the current first collating symbol.  Following this pattern, `a` would become:

```
<U0061> <a>;<BAS>;<MIN>;<a> # 198 a
```

`A` would become:

```
<U0041> <a>;<BAS>;<CAP>;<a> # 517 A
```

`b` would become:

```
<U0062> <a>;<BAS>;<MIN>;<b> # 233 b
```

`B` would become:

```
<U0042> <a>;<BAS>;<CAP>;<b> # 550 B
```

and so on for the rest of the letters.

Once you have created a customized version of `iso14651_t1_common`, follow the instructions in [the answer linked above](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/288333/how-can-i-make-ls-show-dotfiles-first-while-staying-case-insensitive/361006#361006) to compile your custom locale.

Answer (score 10):

Setting `LC_COLLATE=C` is not always sufficient to sort uppercase before lowercase. You may need to set `LC_ALL=C`.

That will also take into account non-alphanumeric and even non-printable characters, but if you don't want that there are options `-d` and `-i` (described in `man sort`) to will turn that off.

It will probably fail badly with multibyte input though, such as UTF-8 with non-ASCII characters.

To get lowercase (in order) before uppercase (in order), the best way I can think of that doesn't involve breaking out a full-fledged programming language is inverting the case of all the letters before the sort, and inverting them back afterwards.

```
tr 'a-zA-Z' 'A-Za-z' < file | LC_ALL=C sort | tr 'a-zA-Z' 'A-Za-z'
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm no expert but I have never seen locale that defines collation like this.   AFAIK this collation is only in C where it is based on [ASCII values](http://www.ascii.cl/).  (Normally I would just solve this by a script.)

However, I have never done this but you might want to look at [localedef(1)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?localedef+1) and [locale(5)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?locale+5) manpages to get understanding of how locales are defined and eventually define your own one.

Also don't forget that if there are any diacritics or special characters, C locale will not treat them as you might want to.  For example, it will not put `á` near `a` or `Ł` near `L`.  In such cases, the language's native locale would be probably a better starting point.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8" sort file
```

Comment: This doesn't sort lowercase before uppercase? http://ideone.com/Gtyg4Z

Comment: Hmm, in my case, it did using your example.

Comment: @unxnut This is incorrect. Without the semicolon, the command would set the environment for `sort`, but with the semicolon the variable is local to the shell and doesn't affect the behavior of `sort`. The semicolon could be kept as is if the variable is also exported, but that would affect other commands as well.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is without needing LC_COLLATE changed (meaning leaving the function as default behavior):

sort -f file

This works on Linux; please refer to your help section for the command in case you are on Unix and running a different version. -f is defined as ignoring case.

Thanks for the rather (&oddly) quick fix and edit to the misplaced grammar, Stephen Rauch.