# gst123 does not play files in right order when playing back folders/

Tags: audio, gstreamer

I have the following problem with the Gstreamer player **gst123**:

when I'm playing back folders gst123 does not play the files in alphabetical order. When I have my files ordered like this:

```
01.mp3
02.mp3
03.mp3
```

I would expect the player to play the files back in this order, which it doesn't. I also did not really grasp which order it is actually using. gst123 does have some options to not play in order:

```
   -z, --shuffle
          Shuffle playlist before playing.

   -Z, --random
          Play files in random order forever.
```

I'm not using any of these.

Does anyone know this problem or a way to fix it?

I'm using gst123 version: 0.3.3-1+b3

**The gstreamer plugins that I'm using are:**

```
gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly/testing,now 1.12.2-1 i386
gstreamer1.0-plugins-good/testing,now 1.12.2-1 i386
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/testing,now 1.12.2-1 i386
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad/testing,now 1.12.2-1 i386
```

for some reasons I was not able to playback MP3 after some upgrades so I also installed:

```
gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3
```

I'm using a:

```
Debian GNU/Linux buster/sid
Kernel: Linux 4.11.0-1-686-pae
```

Comment: Does the playback order match the output of `ls -f`? If so it is probably just using the order that readdir() returns. A fix might be to list the files explicitly with directory/*

Comment: @icarus **much thanks**, you fixed it. WOW I can use may favourite player again. -> if you want to turn this into an answer? It is already as much as accepted :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no requirement that the entries are stored in any particular order. Programs like `ls` typically sort them, and the shell also sorts them when it expands filenames. The sorting is determined by the locale, and in particular the LC_ALL or LC_COLLATE environment variables. You can create custom locales if you would like particular sorting orders, [see these answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75341/specify-the-sort-order-with-lc-collate-so-lowercase-is-before-uppercase)

To see the unsorted list of filenames use `ls -fa` (f for fast, a for all), which just lists the files in the order that readdir() presents them.

For the filenames shown in the question, just giving directoryname/* will give the filenames in the correct order to the player.