# Sorting ls output respecting locale but not ignoring nonalphanumeric characters

Tags: ls, sort, locale

Let's say I have a directory with the files `_b`, `a`, `c`, `č`, `d`. I would like to sort the files according to the cs_CZ.UTF8 locale but *without* ignoring the underscore, ie like this: `_b a c č d`.

Currently, `ls` (and `ls | sort` as well) sorts the files like this: `a  _b  c  č  d`.
All answers I have found suggest using `LC_COLLATE=C`, but that changes the ordering to
this: `_b  a  c  d  č` (notice that `č` is now at the end, not between `c` and `d` as it is supposed to be).

Is there any way to achieve this goal?

Note that I also care about other characters than underscore, ie I would like `a-n.pdf a-p.pdf a.pdf c č d` sort in this order and not `a-n.pdf a.pdf a-p.pdf c č d`.
(EDIT: Actually, `a.pdf a-n.pdf a-p.pdf c č d` is also fine, as long as the non-alphanumeric characters are not ignored.)

The following are not the answers I am looking for:

- using `LC_COLLATE=C` as explained above,
- using shell expansion such as `ls _*; ls [^_]*` because the question is not only about underscores.

Comment: That's an interesting challenge; it might be helpful to either copy, or move your sample data / expected results into a table to make it a little easier to understand how hyphens and underscores should be handled.  The help page https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables shows the markdown for tables.

Comment: When you edit your question, you will probably want to include the `[locale]` tag also.  Have you looked at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/421908/90290 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/39827/90290 yet?

Comment: @MarkStewart I don't care exactly whether how exactly non-alphanumeric characters are ordered as long as they are *not ignored completely*. Thus `a.pdf a-n.pdf a-p.pdf` is OK, as is `a-n.pdf a-p.pdf a.pdf`, but not `a-n.pdf a.pdf a-p.pdf` as that clearly ignores the hyphens/periods. I have tried to clarify this in the question.

Comment: @MarkStewart Thanks for the pointers, I understand there is no easy solution and I would have to learn how to write my own LC_COLLATE rules. I might do that once I have the free time… It seems strange, however, that no one's ever thought about this before (even though this is how collation works e.g. in Windows Explorer).

Comment: Also, this might be a case of the Mandela effect, but I think I remember the sorting in ls working like this in some Linux distros some 10–15 years ago.

Comment: It's funny you mention Windows Explorer; it does sort filenames quite well, even `version1.txt`, `version2.txt`, ... `version10.txt` does sort "correctly" with `version10.txt` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

On a GNU system, appending NULs to non-alphas may help:

```
$ ls | sed 's/[^[:alpha:]]/&\x0/g' | sort | tr -d '\0'
_b
a
c
č
d
```

That assumes file names don't contain newline characters. Generally, you can't sort lists of file names with `sort` as file names can very well be made of several lines themselves.

You could replace the newlines within filenames with `/` here before sorting. With `zsh`:

```
print -rNC1 -- *(N) | # print NUL-delimited
  tr '\n\0' '/\n' |
  sed 's/[^[:alpha:]]/&\x0/g' |
  sort |
  tr -d '\0' |
  tr '/' '\n'
```

Or to keep the list NUL-delimited so it can be post-processed:

```
print -rNC1 -- *(N) | # print NUL-delimited
  tr '\n\0' '/\n' |
  sed 's/[^[:alpha:]]/&\x0/g' |
  sort |
  tr -d '\0' |
  tr '/\n' '\n\0'
```

The `strcoll()` API that is used for sorting takes two NUL-terminated strings. Traditional `sort` implementations only support text input and text input precludes NULs so they're fine. GNU `sort` however, like GNU implementations of most standard text utilities do support NULs with their input.

I don't know how exactly GNU `sort` handles lines with NULs, but my guess would be that it breaks the lines on NULs and compares segments one to one. So, when comparing `foo_\0car` with `foobar_\0more` for instance, `foo_` is compared with `foobar_` and comes first.

You can also define the order of `zsh` globs using arbitrary transformations with the `oe` (`o`rder based on the `e`valuation of some code) or `o+function` glob qualifiers. But before calling `strcoll()`, [`zsh` removes the NULs](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2017/msg00893.html), so you can't use the same transformation as used for GNU `sort` above.

Instead, there, you could add `0`s before sequences of non-alphas and `1`s before sequences of alphas:

In `~/.zshrc`

```
set -o extendedglob
mysort() {
  REPLY=${REPLY//(#m)[^[:alpha:]]##/0$MATCH}
  REPLY=${REPLY//(#m)[[:alpha:]]##/1$MATCH}
}
```

Then:

```
$ print -rC1 -- *(No+mysort)
_b
a
c
č
d
```

Comment: Boy, that is a lot easier than a possible solution I had spinning in my head, of adding a "sorting" column to the output of `ls`, that would hide non-alphanumeric characters, pipe to sort, then pipe to `awk` to omit the sorting column!

Comment: This looks cool. Could you please explain how this works a bit more? What is the role of NULs in sorting?

Comment: @NikolaBenes, see edit.