# Nemo file manager is completely ignoring `_` at the beginning of directory name, when sorting

Tags: filenames, sort, nemo

Ex. suppose some directories are named

```
absorbing
appreciate
arrive
connect
depend
drop
few
fold
littlel
popcorn
shrill
sticky
```

In Windows, if I put `_` before the directories, it would be at the top, like this.

```
_connect
_few
_little
_shrill
absorbing
appreciate
arrive
depend
drop
fold
popcorn
sticky
```

However, the same directories look the following when sorted alphabetically in Nemo 4.0.6 (to be specific, Linux Mint 19.1, Cinnamon 4.0.10)

```
absorbing
appreciate
arrive
_connect
depend
drop
_few
fold
_little
popcorn
_shrill
sticky
```

So, the sort algorithm, in Nemo is completely ignoring `_` at the beginning of directory name.

I want the sorting to work like in the first listing, is there any way to do that?

Comment: (no time to write this up, leaving as pointer for someone) — `ls` will do this too, it's the default sorting in at least en_US.UTF-8. LC_COLLATE=C will not.

Comment: Linking in: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39827/how-do-i-make-ls-sort-underscore-characters-first

Comment: This may be a locale issue, and similar to the issue here: [Is it possible to make thunar sort by ASCII order?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/10581)

Comment: That's consistent with the [ISO14651 standard](https://standards.iso.org/iso-iec/14651/ed-4/ISO14651_2016_TABLE1_en.txt) (see line `<U005F> IGNORE;IGNORE;IGNORE;<U005F> % LOW LINE` meaning `_` is to be ignored for sorting).

Comment: This seems like a locale issue, the kernel doesn't sort the file names for you. It's probably configurable in other OS's too, and comparing to them doesn't really help you in finding a way to change the behaviour.

Comment: If your goal is to sort the directories alphabetically before the files, there's no need to go primitive with underscores. Take a look at the `View` section of Nemo's `Preferences`. There you should find a `Sort folders before files` option to check that should do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

I tested this solution on Linux Mint 19.3.

First go ahead and read [nemo file sort order differs from /bin/ls](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/issues/2247) to have a little background.

**We have two steps:**

1. Modify Nemo so that it sorts according to our locale.
2. Edit `/usr/share/i18n/locales/iso14651_t1_common` for the locale to sort according to our liking.

#### 1. Modify Nemo

The main guide in on [GitHub](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/issues/2247#issuecomment-579601246).

```
git clone https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo
```

Now we have to edit `nemo/libnemo-private/nemo-file.c`

Remove:

```c
/* Files that start with these characters sort after files that don't. */
#define SORT_LAST_CHAR1 '.'
#define SORT_LAST_CHAR2 '#'
```

Replace:

```c
static int
compare_by_display_name (NemoFile *file_1, NemoFile *file_2)
{
    const char *name_1, *name_2;
    const char *key_1, *key_2;
    gboolean sort_last_1, sort_last_2;
    int compare=0;

    name_1 = nemo_file_peek_display_name (file_1);
    name_2 = nemo_file_peek_display_name (file_2);

    sort_last_1 = name_1 && (name_1[0] == SORT_LAST_CHAR1 || name_1[0] == SORT_LAST_CHAR2);
    sort_last_2 = name_2 && (name_2[0] == SORT_LAST_CHAR1 || name_2[0] == SORT_LAST_CHAR2);

    if (sort_last_1 && !sort_last_2) {
        compare = +1;
    } else if (!sort_last_1 && sort_last_2) {
        compare = -1;
    } else if (name_1 == NULL || name_2 == NULL) {
        if (name_1 && !name_2)
            compare = +1;
        else if (!name_1 && name_2)
            compare = -1;
    } else {
        key_1 = nemo_file_peek_display_name_collation_key (file_1);
        key_2 = nemo_file_peek_display_name_collation_key (file_2);
        compare = g_strcmp0 (key_1, key_2);
    }

    return compare;
}
```

with:

```c
static int
compare_by_display_name (NemoFile *file_1, NemoFile *file_2)
{
    const char *key_1, *key_2;
    int compare=0;

    key_1 = nemo_file_peek_display_name_collation_key (file_1);
    key_2 = nemo_file_peek_display_name_collation_key (file_2);
    compare = strcmp (key_1, key_2);

    return compare;
}
```

And Replace:

```
file->details->display_name_collation_key = g_utf8_collate_key_for_filename (display_name, -1);
```

with:

```
file->details->display_name_collation_key = g_utf8_collate_key (display_name, -1);
```

Now turn on **source code repositories** in Software Sources.

Then inside `nemo` directory, issue the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep nemo 
dpkg-buildpackage 
cd .. && sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Then <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>backspace</kbd> to restart Xorg.

[image]

#### 2. Modify `iso14651_t1_common`

Open `/usr/share/i18n/locales/iso14651_t1_common` as admin.

Replace:

```
<U005F> IGNORE;IGNORE;IGNORE;<U005F> # 33 _
```

with:

```
<U005F> <RES-2>;IGNORE;IGNORE;<U005F> # 33 _
```

Run `sudo locale-gen`

**Acknowledgements**

1. [Michael Webster](https://github.com/mtwebster), taught me to [build Nemo from source](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/issues/2308#issuecomment-578475001).
2. [bjd-pfq](https://github.com/bjd-pfq) found out the [issue with
   g_utf8_collate_key_for_filename](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/issues/2247#issuecomment-577312885).
3. [Steven Xu](https://github.com/stevenxxiu) Directed me towards [patching Nemo](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/issues/2247#issuecomment-577584640).
4. The two posts that helped me understand
   `/usr/share/i18n/locales/iso14651_t1_common` was by [beandip](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/228066/beandip).
   The answers are, [How can I make “ls” show dotfiles first while
   staying case-insensitive?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/361006/206574) & [Specify the sort order with
   LC_COLLATE so lowercase is before uppercase](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/361021/206574).

**P.S.** Previous version of this answer can be found in [revisions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/515840/revisions).